# Pick only columns name from csv files without reading entire data, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to find list of columns present in more than 500 csv files. Read only columns & put in dataframe or list and later I want to export to csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas` can easily extract only certain columns and write out a new CSV file for you:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('input.csv', usecols=[1, 3], index_col=1)
data.to_csv('output.csv')
```

If you wanted to extract the same two columns from multiple files into a single output, you could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

combined_data = pd.DataFrame()

for csv_file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_file, usecols=[1, 3], index_col=1, skiprows=1, header=None, names=['Col1', 'Col2'])
    combined_data = combined_data.append(data)

combined_data.to_csv('output.csv')
```

This might need tweaking depending on whether or not your files have headers and the same column names.

---

To extract the headers from all of the files (without loading the whole file), you could simply use the CSV library as follows:

```
import csv
import glob

with open('headers.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_headers:
    csv_headers = csv.writer(f_headers)

    for csv_file in glob.glob('input*.csv'):
        with open(csv_file, 'r', newline='') as f_csv:
            csv_headers.writerow([csv_file] + next(csv.reader(f_csv)))
```

This would also put the filename as the first entry on each row.

Comment: thanks, but I wanted column name, this also helps for my other requirements.

Comment: So in effect you are trying to create a CSV file containing all of the header rows from your 500 files?

Comment: I just want to know columns present in all the 500 csv files

Comment: I have added a simple CSV reader which should help. It adds the filename as the first entry on each row.

Comment: thanks this is I wanted